# System completly freezes often (maybe chromium-vaapi)

Tags: arch-linux, chrome, freeze, journalctl

My system freezes and the only solution is to force shutdown it. I'm not sure but maybe the problem is due chromium-vaapi , any missconfiguration or something.
I'm in 5.4.13-arch1-1 #1 SMP PREEMPT.
[Here](https://pastebin.com/1NnT1n6A) my journalctl with the freeze.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, this is a **GPU** driver bug. It's already in your paste.

```
ene 22 18:59:01 dlag-pc kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: GPU HANG: ecode 9:1:0x00000000, hang on rcs0
ene 22 18:59:01 dlag-pc kernel: GPU hangs can indicate a bug anywhere in the entire gfx stack, including userspace.
ene 22 18:59:01 dlag-pc kernel: Please file a _new_ bug report on bugs.freedesktop.org against DRI -> DRM/Intel
ene 22 18:59:01 dlag-pc kernel: drm/i915 developers can then reassign to the right component if it's not a kernel issue.
ene 22 18:59:01 dlag-pc kernel: The GPU crash dump is required to analyze GPU hangs, so please always attach it.
ene 22 18:59:01 dlag-pc kernel: GPU crash dump saved to /sys/class/drm/card0/error
ene 22 18:59:01 dlag-pc kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: Resetting rcs0 for hang on rcs0
ene 22 18:59:01 dlag-pc kernel: [drm:gen8_reset_engines [i915]] *ERROR* rcs0 reset request timed out: {request: 00000001, RESET_CTL: 00000001}
ene 22 18:59:01 dlag-pc kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: Resetting chip for hang on rcs0
ene 22 18:59:01 dlag-pc kernel: [drm:gen8_reset_engines [i915]] *ERROR* rcs0 reset request timed out: {request: 00000001, RESET_CTL: 00000001}
```

The [bug](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/intel/issues/673) is known to affect `kernel:5.3` & `kernel:5.4`. It's already resolved in `kernel:5.5` tree.

Comment: And can I upgrade to 5.5? I think for arch isn't ready yet.

Comment: @dlag: Yes, it's better to wait for upstream to release it. As of today, it's `5.5-rc7`